# Push UITabBarController from UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a **UINavigationController** and I am navigating from one view to another successfully. But at some point I want to show a **UITabBarController** with some views.

(I select a user from a list and I want to show his profile (containing multiple views) with tabs)

I searched, tried and nothing...
I can't find someone that tried something like this.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to create the nib file for **UITabBarController** and how to push it from a navigation controller?

Comment: try my answer, it tested one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an easy task, made a UIViewController and in that add as subview UITabBarController. Now you can simply push it using navigationcontroller to that controller.

```
MainScreen *mainScreen = [[MainScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil];
    mainScreen.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainScreen animated:YES];
```

And on MainScreen controller's viewDidLoad method add TabBarController as subview in self.view. Also made outlet of tabbarcontroller and conect it with interface builder TabBarController object.

Comment: I used [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];

Comment: you can't add a tab bar controller as a subview

Answer (score 2):

Dont do that. add tabbatcontroller to ur mainwindow class. whenever you need tabar in app. just remove UINavigationController and add UITabBarController.

or 
add add tabbatcontroller to ur mainwindow class and
just present tababrcontroller from current viewcontroller.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.tCtr.selectedIndex = index;
delegate.tCtr.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:delegate.tCtr animated:YES];
```

Comment: Works like a champ! Posting monotouch code to help people out as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not just re-assign your new UIViewController's array to UITabBarController's viewControllers property? That will do the trick.

```
- (void)addNewControllers {
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray array];
    UIViewController *c0 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [controllers addObject: c0];

    UIViewController *c1 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [controllers addObject: c1];

    UIViewController *c2 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [controllers addObject: c2];

    [myTabBarController setViewControllers:controllers];
}
```

call above function

then [self.navcont pushviewcontroller:mytabbarcontroller animated:yes];

here change those uiviewcontroller to ur own by replacing the nibname function with using IB

for more

http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/

Answer (score 0):

Since @Rakesh Bhatt's answer worked for me, here's the equivalent Monotouch code to get it running. My situation was that I have a SignInViewController I show first, then replace it with a UITabBarController subclass.

```
        AppDelegate.Navigation.SelectedIndex = 0;
        AppDelegate.Navigation.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal;
        PresentViewController (AppDelegate.Navigation, true, null);
```